# Is there a benefit to using unevolved Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-revolution-online

I'm new at PRO, but it seems that lots of players level up pokemons without evolving them.

Is that a trick so level 100 pokemons stats are better? If I decline a pokemon to evolve, can I envolve him later?

Comment: The title is misleading, it suggests that you are asking if it is possible to level up without evolution.  Perhaps a title like "Is there a benefit to using unevolved Pokémon?" would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PRO, unevolved Pokemon require less EXP to level up. Raising unevolved Pokemon is thus much faster than raising evolved Pokemon, since the EXP curve is more steep as well.

The caveat is that if you accidentally forget to evolve your Pokemon, they will not be able to evolve. This applies specifically to those Pokemon which evolve by level up. You can ask the staff to help force evolve the Pokemon which evolve by level up alone due to a game glitch, but specific level up (such as levelling up in a specific location) cannot be forced.

To be on the safe side, I would recommend allowing your Pokemon to evolve when they hit level 97 (Level 98 is the last chance you have if it is a 3-stage Pokemon).

Last note, I wouldn't recommend doing that until you completed the main story line, when you unlocked all the areas where you can grind. Otherwise it can be a struggle to progress in the game.

Answer (score -1):

If PRO is anything like every official Pokémon game it's actually a bad idea to keep them at lower evolution levels because they are naturally stronger after evolution, even if the pre-evolution is boosted with items and the post-evolution is not and they're the same level, the evolved version will often (if not always) be stronger overall.

People have personal preferences though, and will ignore maximum power for nostalgia.

Edit/correction:

PRO does use the same data as other Pokémon games, they've just increased some of the numbers according to their own documentation. For example you get more XP in this game, but the XP needed to level up is also increased to help balance that out. Their documentation also says that leaving a Pokémon at a lower evolution helps it level up faster, so yes, that is a trick.

As for the rest, based on other Pokémon games (i.e. the following is speculation), the lv100 stats will be the same no matter when the evolution occurs, and classically you can stop and evolution and then continue it later so there's no reason for that to be different here either.